# The order of Surahs in Prayer?

Tags: salat, quran-recitation

In what order shall the Suras be recited in Prayer? Should it be in the order we have in the physical copy of the Quran? Can Surat Fatiha be recited after Surat Fatiha? Can we recite the same Sura in two rakats?

According to this [website](http://www.islamcan.com/salat/duas/index.shtml):

> After Surah Fatiha - recite any Surah from the Quran. **Please note that the surah recited in the first rakath should be longer than the one recited in the second rakath.**

If that's the case, what does he mean by **longer**? Is it the number of verses? If so, is it wrong to recite Surat Al-Ikhlas(four verses) before Surat Al-Falaq(five verses)?

Comment: It would be much better if you split this into 3 questions: *1)* In what order shall the Suras be recited in Prayer? Should it be in the order we have in the physical copy of the Quran? *2)* Can Surat Fatiha be recited after Surat Fatiha? *3)* Can we recite the same Sura in two rakats? It's never harmful to do so, in fact I think it's better and easier for Googlers :)

Comment: the order should be the same as in Quran - at least not reverse. within one Prayer no Sura should be repeated except for the obigatory reading of Fatiha thus one should not read Fatiha after Fatiha in the same Rakat.

Comment: i know only Surah Fatiha and khul ka surah can i use khul ka surah after surah fatiha,in all four rakaths.

Answer (score 3):

- You can recite in any order you like, however within the same surrah you have to maintain the order.

For example, if in the first Raka read from verse `30 to 35` from Al-Kahf, in the second Rakah you can **not** read something before Ayah 30 t *within* surrat `AlKahf`; however you can read from other Surrah even if it was before `Alkahf` e.g. `Albaqarah`.

If you reversed the order *within* the same surrah it is called "Tankeeth" in Arabic and it is not allowed.

The evidence that it is allowed to read Surras in any order is that the prophet peace upon him once in the prayer read `Al-baqarah`, then `Al-Nisa` then `A'l Imran` which are not in order.

- From sunnah prophet was reading longer in the first Rakah which is recommended but it is not Wajib.
- Reciting a surrah after the Fatiha is *Sunnah* not wajib but majority of scholars *dislike* repeating the Fatiha twice in the same Rakah.

Comment: I think the correct word is "tankees" inversion. There are a whole lot of laws about tankees,
inversion of letters, ayats , surahs etc.
I add topic I came across. http://islamqa.info/tankees

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to read the surahs in an orderly fashion e.g: surah al- baqarah, surah al-imran then surah al-nisa etc. Because the prophet (saw) read the surahs without an order. Moreover, You can not read in reverse  this is bad and is called TANKEETH in arabic.