# Can only a part of a long surah be recited during prayers?

Tags: salat, quran-recitation

There are some very long surahs in the Qur'an, such as Al-Baqarah, Al-Imran, and An-Nisa. While I have read some hadith, such as [this one](https://sunnah.com/nasai/20/67), about such long surahs being recited during obligatory prayers during the period of revelation, presumably it is not practical for most people to do so at present times due to busy work schedules.

If a surah is being recited during a rakat of one of the five obligatory prayers, is it necessary to recite it in its entirety or it is acceptable to recite only a part of it, such as the [ayat ul-kursi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Baqara_255)? If it is acceptable to recite only a portion, what are the rules governing what length must be recited in order for the prayer to be valid?

Comment: This question has several answers on the site from the sunni perspective. You should check first whether you can find an answer before posting your question.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I would appreciate seeing your links. Nothing relevant appeared when I searched for it, and none of the suggestions that popped up when I was writing the post were relevant either.

Comment: With the edited tags it should be easier to find them, once I'll have time I might add the relevant posts: [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/44154/13438) is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can recite a small portion of a long Surah. As I know your recitation should be at least three small ayahs or a long ayah which equal to three small ayahs and the sky is the limit! Zajakallahu Khair.

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/20043/it-is-mustahabb-to-recite-a-complete-soorah-after-al-faatihah-in-prayer

Answer (score 1):

In the first and second rak'ahs of the obligatory daily prayers, the worshiper (according to the "Ehtiate-Wajeb" [obligatory precaution]) must recite a complete surah after the praise. Unless the time for prayer is short, or a person is forced not to recite the Surah, as if he were afraid that if he recited the Surah, he would be harmed by a thief or a predator, or something else.

Reference: https://article.tebyan.net/421289/

Comment: So if he starts surah al Bakara will  someone finish the whole surah? Your answer indicates that.

Comment: I presume: It will be feasible for him/her to finish it entirely albeit seems to be tough/long! although I think there is no necessity to recite it to ...!